# Ubuntu 13.04 boots and starts up slowly

Tags: boot, 13.04, startup

After I updated from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 my operating system is very slow.

Until I see the login screen it takes very long and after logging in I wait for about a minute...

I have dual boot with Windows 8 (for visual studio only)

My laptop's configuration is:

```
Lenovo B570
CPU i3-2330 2.20Ghz
Ram 6Gb
HDD 500Gb
VGA Intel HD 3000 (driver installed)

Swap 4Gb
Ubuntu 64bit
```

Comment: the same problem (and hardware My Lenovo G770). It take more than 3 minutes after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have too much startup aplication?
too look that you can search on dash "startup application" 
remove the application you not use for the startup,
hope this can solve your problem

Comment: I have only DropBox and Jupiter(power management) this weren't making problems on 12.10